# Button Click Simulation does not work on Microsoft website

Tags: javascript

While the simple code below that simulates a mouse click works well on many websites, for some reason it does not work with login.microsoftonline.com. The "Sign In" button seems to be clicked, but does not submit, like if clicked manually using a mouse.

What I am missing? thanks.

```
function click(e) {
   var myEvt = new CustomEvent("click", {bubble: true, cancelable: true});
   e.dispatchEvent(myEvt);
}

click(document.querySelector('span#cred_sign_in_button'));
```

Chrome 35

Comment: Oh Mozart, you should stick to writing music. Mozilla Firefox 29

Comment: Works for me (in the console). Chrome 35.0.1916.114

Comment: folks it works when the user/pass fields are empty, but when you fill these fields the problem occurs.

Answer (score 0):

For those who might encounter such problem, please allow me to describe how I solved it.

The problem was that the click has occurred before the "Sign In" button -- at the very javascript heavy website -- was ready. That's probably because there was some processing happening in the background after entering the user ID and password. Which explains why it clicks when the input fields are empty but does not when they are filled.

The solution was to add a timer, that wait a bit then clicks. Worked perfectly!

Code to reproduce the problem:

```
document.getElementById('cred_userid_inputtext').value = "Wolfgang@Amadeus.org";
document.getElementById('cred_password_inputtext').value = "http://youtu.be/Rb0UmrCXxVA";

function click(e) {
var myEvt = new CustomEvent("click", {bubble: true, cancelable: true});
e.dispatchEvent(myEvt);
}

click(document.querySelector('span#cred_sign_in_button'));
```

Code that solved the problem after adding a timer.

```
document.getElementById('cred_userid_inputtext').value = "Wolfgang@Amadeus.org";
document.getElementById('cred_password_inputtext').value = "http://youtu.be/Rb0UmrCXxVA";

function click(e) {
var myEvt = new CustomEvent("click", {bubble: true, cancelable: true});
e.dispatchEvent(myEvt); 
}

setInterval (function() { click(document.querySelector('span#cred_sign_in_button')); }, 25);
```